# RxJava - Mapping a result of list to another list

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to convert every object in my list to an another object. But in doing so my code stucks in converting them back to List

```
override fun myFunction(): LiveData<MutableList<MyModel>> {
    return mySdk
            .getAllElements() // Returns Flowable<List<CustomObject>>
            .flatMap { Flowable.fromIterable(it) }
            .map {MyModel(it.name!!, it.phoneNumber!!) }
            .toList() //Debugger does not enter here
            .toFlowable()
            .onErrorReturn { Collections.emptyList() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .to { LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it) }
}
```

Everything is fine until mapping. But debugger does not even stop at toList or any other below toList. How can I solve this?

Comment: what is getAllElements

Comment: why don't you just `.map {}`  the list that getAllElements returns? You don't need flatmap

Comment: Maybe I can in here but in another method I need to use each object in my list and  send separate requests with them. In that case I will need flatMap so I am trying to learn why toList() function never gets executed

Comment: toList is not executed because your flatmap doesn't propagate an onComplete event, and toList is waiting for that. Read this https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3861

Comment: Sorry, I gave wrong information. getAllElements return Flowable<List<CustomObject>>

Comment: If it does not propagate an onComplete then debugger should not come to map but it does?

Comment: no. Map is executed because it will map each of the emitted items, but it does not go beyond that because it is forever waiting for more items

Comment: Thanks, you can write the working example without flatmap,toList /with map, I will accept the answer

Comment: I'll leave that to you. Once you figure it out, just post the answer yourself

Comment: Ok I will, one last question. Would flatMapSingle help in here?

Comment: probably not, unless you want to end up with a single. But that makes little sense for LiveData

Comment: I solved it with flatMapSingle, can you check it please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `flatMap()` you'll only flatten the `Flowable` of lists to a single `Flowable` of the elements. Calling `toList()` on it requires the `Flowable` to complete and therefore you'll most likely never get there. If you only want to map the elements in the list and have an item with the new list emitted, you should do the mapping within `flatMap()` or maybe try using `concatMap()` to keep the order:

```
...
.concatMapSingle { list ->
    Observable.fromIterable(list).map {
        MyModel(it.name!!, it.phoneNumber!!)
    }.toList()
}
...
```

Comment: Hi, upvoted your answer as this will also work. When should I prefer concatMapSingle over flatMapSingle?

Comment: @Cem when you want to preserve the "original" order of the items

Comment: So I think same pattern can be used if I have more than one flat map.
                mySdk.getAllElements()
                .flatMap { Flowable.fromIterable(it) }
                .flatMap { aMethodThatReturns Flowable<CustomObject>}
                .toList()
                .toFlowable()

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to this. Thanks to Tim for leading me to right answer.

```
override fun myFunction(): LiveData<MutableList<MyModel>> {
    return mySdk
            .getAllElements() // Returns Flowable<List<CustomObject>>
            .flatMapSingle { Observable.fromIterable(it).map { MyModel(it.name!!, it.phoneNumber!!) }.toList() }
            .toFlowable()
            .onErrorReturn { Collections.emptyList() }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .to { LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it) }
}
```