# RxJava using toList after flatMap fails as flatMap isn't complete

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have three objects (say A,B,C) and to get C I need B, and to get A, I need B. In screen I need to display a property of A together with a property of C. Even though I can get all necessary data, since I use flatMap which do not have onComplete, toList() does not get executed. Here is my code.

For every a in List I need to get c and I need to return a list of type ResultMode which includes properties of a and c.

```
override fun methodICall(): LiveData<MutableList<ResultModel>> {
        return mySdk
                .getAllA() //Returns Flowable<List<A>>
                .flatMap { Flowable.fromIterable(it) }
                .flatMap { helperMethod(it) }
                .toList() // Does not get executed as flatMap isnt completed
                .toFlowable()
                .onErrorReturn { Collections.emptyList() }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .to { LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it) }
    }

    private fun helperMethod(a:A): Flowable<ResultModel> {
        return mySdk
                .getB(a.propertyOne!!) // Returns Single<B>
                .flatMap { mySdk.getC(it.property!!) } // get C returns Single<C>
                .map {
                    ResultModel(name= a.name,
                            date = c.date.toString(), 
                            message = it.messageId!!
                         )
                }.toFlowable()
    }
```

Note: I asked a similar question earlier today but it did not require using flatmap more than once. You can view my solution to that in this link

[RxJava - Mapping a result of list to another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317686/rxjava-mapping-a-result-of-list-to-another-list)

My Effort (Which is probably wrong)
Here is my effort of transforming first method (for second method I just remove to Flowable and return single) but it has a long way to go and I think I am in the wrong path.

```
 override fun methodICall(): LiveData<MutableList<ResultModel>> {
        return mySdk
                .getAllA()
                .concatMapSingle { Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                        .map { helperMethod(it) }
                        .toList()
                }
                .onErrorReturn { Collections.emptyList() }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .to { LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it) // here it is single. I think it is because two maps are applied both to helperMethod itself and inside helper method to result model}
    }
```

Comment: Does `mySdk.getAllA()` is infinite? or it completes immediately after posting value?

Comment: It is infinite hence I cant use toList and I opted to use concatMapSingle. That is the source of my problem

Comment: Yes, you are right. For infinite observables `toList()` not working because it's (operator) logic is based on `onComplete()`. You are moving on the right way with `Effort`. Please, note that if you don't want transform `Observable` to `Single`, you can call `toList().toObservable()` - that allow you listen not only first emission of infinite source, but listen until disposed.

Comment: Hi Const I achieved my goal but my solution is really really messy and I don't think it is the right way to solve it and there can be a lot of bugs. I am posting it in 10 minutes. Can you review it?

Comment: I will try during hour

Comment: I tried to do it with one other method but after executing toList my return type is LiveData<MutableList<Single<MyModel>>>. I want to get rid of single in return type, can I do that

Comment: One more problem that is present in both my and Bob's answer. If bItem.propertyOfB is null, emptyList is returned as a result from onErrorReturn. If have 3 A and even if one of their B's property is null currently I get an empty list as result. In this case I want to get the result of other 2 in my list, how can I do it

Comment: You can use `filter()` before to skip all items with `bItem.propertyOfB == null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : I found another solution

```
 override fun methodICall(): LiveData<MutableList<ResultModel>> {
        return mySdk
                .getAllA()
                .concatMapSingle {
                    Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                            .flatMap { a ->
                                mySdk.getB(a.propertyOfA!!)
                                        .flatMap { b -> chatbotSdk.getC(b.propertyOfB!!) }
                                        .map { it ->

                                            ResultModel(name = a.name,
              message = it.body!!)
              }.toFlowable() 
                            } .toList()    }
                .onErrorReturn { Collections.emptyList() }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .to { LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it) }
    }
```

---

Original Solution

This is my solution but I think this solution is really messy and it can be improved a lot.

```
  data class AtoBDTO(var name: String, var b: Flowable<B>) // I wanted to map one object to more than one so I created this. Probably there is a way to do it with rx functions.
    data class BtoCDTO(var name: String, var c: Flowable<C>)



    override fun methodICall(): LiveData<MutableList<ResultModel>> {
            return mySdk
                    .getAllA() // Returns Flowable<List<A>>
                    .concatMapSingle {
                        Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                                .map { AtoBDTO(it.name!!,    
 mySdk.getB(it.propertyOfA!!).toFlowable()) }  //getB returns Single B
                                .toList()
                    }
                    .concatMapSingle {
                        Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                                .map {
                                    BtoCDTO(it.name,
                                            it.b.concatMapSingle { mySdk.getC(it.propertyOfB!!) }) // getC returns Single C
                                }
                                .toList()
                    }
                    .concatMapSingle {
                        Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                                .map {
                                    ResultModel(name = it.name,
                                            message = it.c.blockingFirst().body!!) // I use blocking first because otherwise I can't get rid of flowable
                                }.toList()
                    }
                    .onErrorReturn { Collections.emptyList() }
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .to { LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it) }
        }
```

Comment: The answer from [@Bob Dalgleish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324132/rxjava-using-tolist-after-flatmap-fails-as-flatmap-isnt-complete?noredirect=1#answer-53326526) looks pretty good and I suppose it what you need

Comment: His answer has getAllA().flatMapIterable{it} instead of  getAllA().flatMap {Flowable.fromIterable(it)} . Does this make any difference? That code still does not execute toList. As getAllA is infinite using toList after flatMapIterable{it} should also fail

Comment: Yes, you are right. But all other chain, he writes is good enough. Use `getAllA().flatMap { Flowable.fromIterable(it).flatMap { mySdk.getB(item.propertyOfA!!)
                    .flatMap( bItem => mySdk.getC( bItem.propertyOfB!! ) )
                    .map( ResultModel( name=item.name, message=it.body!! ) ) }.toList().toObservable() }`

Comment: I could not make it work, maybe I am doing something wrong. By the way I solved the problem with a better way (compared to my old solution). Is it an ok solution?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a good reason to continually deconstruct and reconstruct lists. Assuming there isn't:

```
override fun methodICall(): LiveData<MutableList<ResultModel>> {
        return mySdk
                .getAllA() // Returns Flowable<List<A>>
                .flatMapIterable(it)
                .concatMapSingle( item => {
                  mySdk.getB(item.propertyOfA!!)
                    .flatMap( bItem => mySdk.getC( bItem.propertyOfB!! ) )
                    .map( ResultModel( name=item.name, message=it.body!! ) )
                 })
                .toList()
                .onErrorReturn { Collections.emptyList() }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .to { LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(it) }
    }
```

Because the `concatMapSingle()` operator knows about each item, its name can be known when it is time to construct the `ResultModel`. Now, you no longer need to tear things apart so often.

Comment: Hi,  I am editing your answer because of syntax errors and return type but this does not work. I dont see the difference between using flatMap  and use iterable inside action and using flatMapIterable{it}. Please feel free to warn me if you think I edited wrong or why this method should work